# Is there a reason to omit $[0]$ from the solution of the inequality $x^4 \ge x^2$?

Tags: inequality, wolfram-alpha

This is the inequality I plugged in: $$x^4 \ge x^2$$
Wolfram Alpha gives me the correct number line, but the interval notation it gives me is missing $\{0\}$. (It gives me $(-∞, -1]$ and $[1, ∞)$, missing $\{0\}$).

[You can test this out if you want.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4+%3E%3D+x%5E2)
Is there something I'm not seeing, or is Wolfram Alpha wrong?

Comment: Could you write out the interval given?

You are correct, 0 should be included.

Comment: What did you type in Wolfram? [It seems correct to me.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E2+%3E%3D+x%5E4)

Comment: @ClementC. I messed up, I meant x^4 >= x^2. I edited the question with a link.

Comment: That's weird, the interval does seem wrong, and doesn't agree with the number line it shows above it.

Comment: I assume that wolfram doesn't treat $[a,a]$ as an interval.

Comment: @kingW3 yes I think this is the point. In that field it tries to determine a or several  proper intervals on which the inequality holds.

Comment: What is the reason for all the down-votes here? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I know the first one was because I gave the wrong inequality and the rest are probably because of the question title before the edit

Comment: I don't get why having curiosity about mathematics and finding out whether some software is doing things bad or not is being downvoted.

Comment: By the way, the notation for the set containing zero is $\{0\}$, not $[0]$. So it should be $(-\infty,-1]\cup\{0\}\cup[1,\infty)$.

Comment: @AkivaWeinbergercolumbus thanks, im just learning about this as a freshman in highschool

Comment: You could also write it as $[0,0]$, since that's the set of points between $0$ and $0$ inclusive.

Comment: @AkivaWeinbergercolumbus yeah but why XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, there is something wrong or at least misleading with the specific subsection "Intervals" of WolframAlpha's output (it does not give all the solutions). Note that the other sections (number line) are right, however.
You can also try [with Mathematica's syntax](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Reduce%5B%7Bx%5E4+%3E%3D+x%5E2%7D%2C+x%2C+Reals%5D), which also gives the right answer:

> Reduce[{x^4 >= x^2}, x, Reals]

You can also use WolframAlpha with more specific inputs: for instance, if you specify "solve"

> solve x^4 >= x^2

[then the result is much less ambiguous.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E4+%3E%3D+x%5E2)

Comment: In this case it does not give any interval notation at all.

Comment: No, but what should it? What is the added value of $(-\infty,-1]\cup[0]\cup[1,\infty)$, compared to what it does give?

Comment: Well not much. But the question is about it. (The other input also outputs all the solutions in other forms, just not in the interval notation.)

Comment: More or less... The question is about whether the "interval section" of WolframAlpha (which is given if you don't specify exactly what you want) is wrong, i.e. can lead to the wrong results when reading or interpreting it... it is the case; but while fixing the interval section of Wolfram is not that easy from the outside, removing the error is definitely within reach.

Comment: I do not think that there is any error there. There is a seems to be misunderstanding to what the line is about. One could just as well reply, ignore that line as the earlier output cells give a correct answer.

Comment: Yes, I have the same feeling: Technically, the OP didn't "ask" any question to WolframAlpha, but just wrote an inequality; the way it interprets the input is somewhat mysterious, but nowhere it is claimed that this subsection lists all the solutions... hence my suggestion of *explicitly* stating in the input what one wants WA to "do" with the inequality.

Answer (score 3):

> It gives me $[1, ∞) \cup (-∞, -1]$

No it doesn't. It gives $[1, \infty)$ and it gives  $(-\infty, -1]$. That is, it gives some intervals on which the inequality holds. Also note, that there is a point "solutions" and then also "solution."

I tend to agree that this behavior is not very intuitive, but I do not think there is an actual error there, and in any case you misrepresent the output.

Comment: So Wolfram Alpha thinks including [0] is redundant?

Comment: No it does not think it is redundant. I think in that field it gives (proper) intervals on which the inequality holds. (Not a description of a set of solutions.)